# How do I calculate the number of zeroes at the end of a number in any base form?

Tags: function-construction

I want to calculate the highest power of a prime p in a given integer n.

For example

```
f: (p, n) --> h

(2,30) ->2
(2,31) ->1
(2,32) ->32

(3,24) ->3
(3,25) ->1
(3,26) ->1
(3,27) ->27
```

For 2 only, I used :

```
f[n__]:= BitAnd[n,-n]
```

For 3, 5 and so on I am thinking of using

```
f[p_,n_]:=BaseForm[n,p]
```

and then counting the number of zeroes this number has at the end, for example:

```
BaseForm[27,3] = 1000(3)
```

So the highest power of 3 in 27 is 3^3 = 27

```
BaseForm[24,3] = 220(3)
```

So the highest power of 3 in 24 is 3^1 = 3

This brings me to my question:

How do I calculate the number of zeroes at the end of a number in any base form?

Comment: Might be something like `p^IntegerExponent[n,p]`. All this is pretty confusing and, among other things. I am pretty sure 3^1 is 3 and not 24.

Comment: How do the values (2,30) -> 2, (2,31) -> 1, (2,32) -> 32 relate to what you are describing to be doing?

Comment: You are correct, 3 is the highest power of 3 in 24. Typo.

Comment: 30 = 2*3*5 so 31 = 2^0 *31, 32 = 2^5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit.**

Actually just `IntegerExponent[n,p]` gives exactly "the number of trailing zeros in the digits of $n$ in base $p$" according to docs. The `p^...` in *Daniel Lichtblau's* comment confused me...

Answering your question "how to calculate the highest power of a prime p"...

```
f[p_, x_] := Last@Last@Select[FactorInteger[x, p], #[[1]] == p &]
f[3,24]
f[2,24]
(* 1  3 *)
```

Do you need to generalize it for any `p`?
You can of course keep dividing (works for not prime `p`):

```
g[n_, p_] := 
  Last@NestWhile[{#[[1]]/p, #[[2]] + 1} &, {n, 0}, 
     IntegerQ[#[[1]]] &] - 1;
g[128,2]
(* 7 *)
```

Comment: I would have done `f[p_?PrimeQ, n_Integer] := 
 FirstCase[ FactorInteger[n], {p, exp_Integer} :> exp ]`? But that seems to be what `IntegerExponent` does.

Comment: @gwr Yes. The `IntegerExponent` is exactly what the OP needs... I din't know it existed, so I kept reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Beautiful, it passes all tests. Must study it before I really grasp it though. Thanks.